# How to mock MySqlConnection using moq

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to mock MySqlConnection using Moq. and it is throwing the below error

System.NotSupportedException: 'Type to mock (MySqlConnection) must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.'

Is there any way to mock the MySqlConnection without changing the code I am trying to write the unit test for?

Comment: Usually you would do database operations in a service or repository and mock that, not MySqlConnection directly.

Comment: As the error suggest you should tend to programm against interfaces and use them in code. Using a concrete class directly will typically end in mayor  problems when testing. Try to change the code under test to use IDbConnection instead of a concrete Connection class.

Comment: @CrowCoder you just push the problem around or you decided to not test your repository.

Comment: @Ralf who said I don't test my repository? I integration test my repository. What is the point of mocking a connection? What would you really be testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an in memory database to mock the application database context and add test data to the in memory db for testing.

Please refer the below code.

```
// Create in memory database

private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

// In the constructor
public ClassConstructor()
{
     dbContext = CreateInMemoryDatabase("InMemory_DB");
     SetupMockData();
 }

private static ApplicationDbContext CreateInMemoryDatabase(string databaseName)
{
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
               .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: $"{databaseName}_{Guid.NewGuid()}")
               .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
               .Options;
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            return context;
}

// Add the mock data
private void SetupMockData()
{
    _dbContext.AddAsync(new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Name"
     });

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```