# How to mock MySqlConnection related method and add test case using Moq

Tags: c#, mysql, moq, xunit

How to mock MySqlConnection related method and add test case using Moq.

Here is my code block, When i am trying to mock MySqlConnection it is showing error.

```
public class MySQLServerConnection 
{
    public async virtual Task<MySqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(MySqlCommand command, MySqlConnection connection)
    {
        MySqlDataReader reader = null;

            try
            {
                reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        return reader;
    }
    public async Task<object> RetryExecuteScalarAsync(MySqlCommand command, MySqlConnection connection)
    {
        object result = new object();

            try
            {
                result = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: // Create a mock MySqlConnection
var connectionMock = new Mock<MySqlConnection>();

Comment: MySqlConnection is not allowed to mock as it is a sealed class

Comment: See the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74852933/how-to-mock-mysqlconnection-using-moq.

Comment: Using IDbconnection is solution suggested in the given post. Thanks @BradleyGrainger